# Assigning column values to each key in python

Tags: python, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

```
data = '{ "data": [ { "add": column1, "pin": column2, "st": column3 }] }'

response = requests.post('https://api.delhivery.io/addfix/IN/v1', headers=headers, data=data)
```

So that each column value is assigned to data

Comment: You should try to provide some more information, and ideally a short example of what 'response' looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not well structured. column1, column2, column3 should be strings but in your data, it is not so I made it a string and done this. I think this will be your required solution.

```
data = '{ "data": [ { "add": "column1", "pin": "column2", "st": "column3" }] }'
data = eval(data)
print(data)
inner_dict = data['data'][0]
value = 0
for i in inner_dict:
    data['data'][0][i] = value
    value += 1
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
{'data': [{'add': 'column1', 'pin': 'column2', 'st': 'column3'}]}
{'data': [{'add': 0, 'pin': 1, 'st': 2}]}
```